# for-each loop generates error but for(it=begin()... doesn't when iterating through std::map containg unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I am getting a strange error when I use a `for-each` style loop over an `std::map` but not when I use an `iterator-incrementing for-loop`. Why is this?

This doesn't generate any errors:

```
  for(auto it = SubjectList.begin(); it!= SubjectList.end(); ++it){
    Hist2D<int> h2d(25,25);
  }
```

However this yields an error:

```
      for(auto subject: SubjectList){
        Hist2D<int> h2d(25,25);
      }
```

As below:

```
ctest.cpp:406:23: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<ListOfNumericLists<int> >]’
     for(auto subject: SubjectList){
                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:62,
                 from ctest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<ListOfNumericLists<int> >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
```

And here is the declaration of the `std::map`

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ListOfNumericLists<int>>> SubjectList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that your map pairs are not copyable, you need to iterate over references

```
for(auto& subject: SubjectList)
```

Or if you do not intend to mutate the elements, you should make them `const` as well

```
for(auto const& subject: SubjectList)
```

This is because each element of your `std::map` is a

```
std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ListOfNumericLists<int>>
```

So since there is a `std::unique_ptr` the elements are not copyable

Answer (score 2):

```
for(auto subject: SubjectList)
```

creates copies named `subject` of every key/value pair in the map. Since your value type is an `std::unique_ptr` which cannot be copied, the pair cannot be copied either. Thus the error.

Try

```
for(const auto &subject: SubjectList)
```

instead.

As a side note, the iterator loop works fine of course, since you not not even access, let alone try to copy, the contents of the map there.